# MacOS VNC with seperate session for each connection

Tags: remote-desktop

I am signed in as user `test` on my Macbook running Big Sur. I want to be able to connect into the same user account `test`, but NOT the same desktop session, so that me physically accessing the computer under `test` has a completely separate desktop session than the remote VNC connection signing into as `test`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible in macOS.